# How to get maximum/largest value from json object with Android?

Tags: android, json

I've json string like this:

```
{"GetReportResult":[
{"bulan":"4","total":"2448","type":"CHEESE1K","uang":"8847823"},{"bulan":"4","total":"572476","type":"ESL","uang":"5863408410"},{"bulan":"4","total":"46008","type":"ESL500ML","uang":"234498301"},{"bulan":"4","total":"228985","type":"UHT","uang":"1367172990"},{"bulan":"4","total":"40995","type":"WHP","uang":"235750452"},{"bulan":"5","total":"5703","type":"CHEESE1K","uang":"134929306"},{"bulan":"5","total":"648663","type":"ESL","uang":"6645764498"},{"bulan":"5","total":"49305","type":"ESL500ML","uang":"266817346"},{"bulan":"5","total":"287867","type":"UHT","uang":"1446897805"},{"bulan":"5","total":"51958","type":"WHP","uang":"631994613"},{"bulan":"6","total":"4390","type":"CHEESE1K","uang":"104527773"},{"bulan":"6","total":"443335","type":"ESL","uang":"4540123082"},{"bulan":"6","total":"28462","type":"ESL500ML","uang":"148290912"},{"bulan":"6","total":"213250","type":"UHT","uang":"1197646870"},{"bulan":"6","total":"27049","type":"WHP","uang":"189802525"}
]}
```

I want to get maximum/largest value of `bulan`, which is `6`. How to do that on android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do  it.

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject("your json string");
JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("GetReportResult");


int max = -1;
for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject temp = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    if(temp.getInt("bulan") > max) 
        max = temp.getInt("bulan");
}

Log.e("Max", "" + max);
```